# How to refresh a part of a webpage?

Tags: php, refresh

I have a PHP page which queries some data from a PostgreSQL database. The data must be always shown up to date, and thus I must refresh it every single second. Right now I'm using  but it refresh  the entire page, which is not what I want to.

What matters to me is actually  in here

I already looked it up and even saw some posts in here, but nothing suited me very well yet. For now (as matter of learning, I'd say) I don't want to get all the PHP query statements, put in another PHP file and refresh it.

I do want a solution for refreshing partially a PHP part of a page.

Comment: You need to use `iframe` or AJAX.

Comment: I tried using iframe and JQuery but whatever I have in between teh iframe tag shows like a gray empty table when I open the page :/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using AJAX.
(Sending requests in the background via JavaScript,
and loading the results into the webpage)

There are a lot of TuTs out there.

Comment: I recommend to use JQuery to do this. here are some examples: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/

Comment: Ok, let's say I managed to extract data with Json, JQuery, AJAX or whatever. How about refreshing only this piece of the page?

Comment: Let JavaScript do that work. Just normal manipulation of HTML

Comment: Jquery has got a lots of commands to do this. you can simply do $('#myelementid').html('<h1>New Html to display</h1>'); Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery, and create a Php Script which when called will print out the data as you like.

Using the $.ajax feature of JQuery will enable to you dynamically load that page, then you can insert it into the page using `$('#MyID').html('New Content');`.

An example of this, using a script called "refresh.php" with the a dynamic variable of 'ID', would be

```
$.post('refresh.php', { ID: 1 }, function(result){
    $('#MyID').html(result);
}
```

You could also use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to separate the output data, via using the JQuery function `$.parseJSON`

An example of this would be

```
$.post('refresh.php', { ID: 1 }, function(result){
    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
    $('#MyID').html(data.ID);
}
```

That would access the JSON encoded variable of "ID", returned from PHP.